# What does this box-shadow query mean and how can I make it corss-browser friendly?

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I have layout inside Adobe Xd. Inside this layout I can export the css values of a design element.

My element has a box shadow. When I try to export it it looks like this:

```
box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px #0000001A;
```

Obviously #0000001A is not a valid hex color string.
I assume the 1A means alpha / opacity but I'm not sure.

surprisingly this syntax works in chrome and as expected not in most other browsers.

How can / should I write this box-shadow query to support all modern browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#0000001A` is equivalent to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)`, where `0.1` is the approximate value of `0x1a / 0xff`. So,

```
box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```

Also, `#RRGGBBAA` format is standard, and works for everything — except, as usual, Microsoft browsers ([table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Browser_compatibility)); not just Chrome.

Comment: @Kaiido Yeah, I wasn't paying attention :) Fixed.

Comment: yes, I thought so... i have to cover edge and IE as well and I've never seen this syntax (#0000001A) before, that's why I was wondering

Comment: Oh and #RRGGBBAA format is *still* (...) in drafts

Comment: @Kaiido: Yes, yes, technically not _yet_ standard. In practice, everything except the black sheep of the browser world supports it.

Answer (score 1):

this hax color string is for black color with opacity 0.1 means "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)" you can apply css using this hex code also.

and for all browser support you have to apply this css to your class.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px #0000001A;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px #0000001A;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px #0000001A;
```

Comment: this still wouldn't work in microsoft browsers as they dont aknowledge #0000001A as a valid hex value

Comment: Okay then you can try the rgba(0,0,0,0.1) instead of #0000001A.